# How to make a div to not scroll when loading a PDF document inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am loading a PDF document inside a div using PDF viewer control from vinnowative PDF to html tool. I want to set the content inside the div should not move on scrolling inside the div. how can i set the properties of the div to not to move when scrolling inside the div?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of the HTML you're using when displaying the PDF on the page?

You could add an `overflow:hidden` CSS property to the containing `div`. This will only show the PDF based on the size of the `div`.

An example:

```
#pdf-container {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:600px;
    height:800px;
}
```